# How can I store substrings generated from a String into a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

The program I am writing is to generate every possible sub-string from a given string (including the word itself) and store these into a `String` array

This is my code:

```
String word = "WOMAN";
String[] res = new String[20];
String sub;
int i, j, k;
int len = word.length();
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= len-i; j++)
    {
        sub = word.substring(i, i+j);
        for(k = 0; k < res.length; k++)
            res[k] = sub;
    }
}
```

I get an error that says - `error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String`. What am I doing wrong?! I want to store each sub-string as an element in the res array.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your function? Maybe there is a even shorter way

Comment: The reason I want to store them in an array is so that I can access any substring. Say, I want to search the word "MAN" from "WOMAN"

Comment: @KrithikaR String.contains? String.indexOf()... Please, read about String library, then ask questions. Here are all your answers : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code contains an identifier `sen` which is not introduced. Also post full exception stacktrace.

Comment: `sen.substring(i, i+j);` what is sen?

Comment: Can you show us a complete example?

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: sen is a typo, sorry about that! It should be word.substring(i, i+j)

Comment: @KrithikaR when I run this code I donot get any such exception. Please paste the code and the stacktrace

Comment: I don't see how the code you have shown us can *possibly* give that compilation error.  Show us a real SSCCE ... not some fictitious stuff that doesn't match your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String[] getSubStrings(String string){
      List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      int i, c, length;
      length = string.length();   
      for( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
      {
         for( i = 1 ; i <= length - c ; i++ )
         {
            result.add(string.substring(c, c+i));
         }
      }
      return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i change little maybe for some help

```
    String word = "WOMAN";
    String[] res = new String[20];
    String sub;
    int i, j, k=0;
    int len = word.length();
    for(i = 0;i < len;i++)
    {
            for(j = 0;j <= len-i;j++,k++)
            {
                sub = word.substring(i, i+j);
                //for(k = 0;k < res.length;k++)
                    res[k] = sub;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
String word = "WOMAN";
String sub = "";
int len = word.length();
List  list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <=len-i; j++)
    {
        sub = word.substring(i, i+j);
        list.add(sub);
    }

}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ArrayList in place of array . Array Size is fixed . So generated sub strings can sometimes over flow or some spaces remain empty if sub string size will be less than the array. Array list grows dynamically with the increasing size .

with Array list one simple solution would be :

public class GenerateStrings {

```
/**
 * Generate substrings of a given string and add them in an arraylist.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> aList=new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the string to split");
    String string=sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=string.length()-i;j++){
            String subString=string.substring(i, i+j);
            aList.add(subString);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(aList);
}
```

}

I Hope it helps .

Answer (score -1):

I simplified your code to this one. This might help.

```
String str = "WOMAN";

List<String> tempArr = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        tempArr.add(str.substring(i - 1, j));
    }
}

String[] res = tempArr.toArray(new String[tempArr.size()]);
```

Comment: for a string ab it only gives a , ab but it is supposed to give a , b , ab